# OpenMP nested loop high performance

Tags: openmp

I have some issues with nested loop in OpenMP (c language). This is what I want to achieve (briefly):

```
int a=0, b=1000;
while(a<b) // Not parallel, must run only once.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // Must be parallel
    {...}

    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) // Must be parallel
    {...}
    a++;
}
```

So I tried thinks like that. But the while loop is execute 4 times:

```
    int a=0, b=1000;
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma parallel omp shared(default)
{
    while(a<b) // parallel, but run 4 times /!\
    {          // add 'single' doesn't compile. (nested regions)
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // works well
        {...}

        #pragma omp for
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) // works well
        {...}
        a++;
    }
}
```

So after looking on the web I found this implementation:

```
    int a=0, b=1000;
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma parallel omp shared(default) num_thread(1)
{
    while(a<b) // parallel and run once
    {
        #pragma parallel omp for num_thread(4)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // works well
        {...}

        #pragma parallel omp for num_thread(4)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) // works well
        {...}
        a++;
    }
}
```

However, this last is slow. It takes 5 to 10 times more time than without OpenMP. So I would like to know if it's possible to avoid declaring parallel region at every step of the while loop? I have already looked at `"single"` or `"master"` but those don't allow `#pragma` regions inside them.

Comment: Just put `#pragma parallel omp for` before your for loops and move on. Your OpenMP implementation will create a thread pool the first time it is called so in the next parallel region the threads don't have to be recreated only reinitialized. You should not have to change your code except to add the pragma statements.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is as follows:

```
int b=1000;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for (int a = 0; a < b; a++)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // works well
        {...}

        #pragma omp for
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) // works well
        {...}
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int b=1000;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int a=0; // !!! must be private
    while(a<b)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // works well
        {...}

        #pragma omp for
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) // works well
        {...}
        a++;
    }
}
```

but the latter is much harder to read/reason about. Your hidden code (`...`) **must not modify `a`** in any case.

Yes, the outer while loop is executed for each thread, but this is correct. Once the threads reach the `omp for` worksharing construct, they will execute the inner loop correctly.

Comment: Thanks but don't work because I need the while loop to be done step by step. Here some thread execute a+2 while a+1 is still not finished.

Comment: All threads execute the same outer iteration due to the implicit barrier for `omp for`. That said, you obviously omit important details about your code in your question. An answer cannot address requirements you don't disclose.

Comment: The OP could just put `#pragma parallel omp for` before the for loops.

Comment: "Here some thread execute a+2 while a+1 is still not finished.". No, it's not. You are forgetting that there is an implicit barrier at the end of a parallel for (unless you use the "nowait" clause). Therefore the behaviour you are worried about cannot happen. (Echoing Zulan :-))